# JQuery Form Validation Error Placement

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

So, I basically want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bUV6S/1/ ...

But I want to do it using the validate.js. Is it possible to target multiple textboxes using:

```
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo($("#textUsername"));
            }
```

...in some way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to multiple elements like this:

```
error.appendTo("#textUsername, #textPassword");
```

Here is the documentation link for "Multiple Selectors": http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Here is a jsfiddle appending to multiple elements: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Wa8EA/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making all of the things you wish to append to in the same css someclass and using a class selector? `error.appendTo(".someclass");` ?